# Email SharePoint Document Externally?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, email

We currently have a SharePoint 2010 intranet site and are wondering whether we can send document stored in a SharePoint library to external emails?

I know you can 'Email a Link' but since they are external they couldn't access that link...

Is there a way to email the entire document as an attachment to an email address?

Answer (score 3):

You would need to download the document then email the document by attaching it manually. This is only OOB functionality. You may have a custom solution that can attach the document for you. You could do this through SharePoint Designer with the right custom actions.

Take a look at this custom SPD workflow action: http://sharepointstuff.codeplex.com/. You could use this workflow action to email the document through a workflow. The user would use the drop-down menu to start the email workflow, and at initiation, they are prompted for the email address they want to send it to.

Another way is to tackle it from a different angle. If you have a common document library that you always email documents out externally, you can use the Connect to Outlook, to connect to that document library and you will have the documents in your Outlook so you can attach it easily in a new email.